# Relative vs Physical addresses in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I recently started learning about memory management and I read about relative addresses and physical addresses, and a question appeared in my mind:

When I print a variable's address, is it showing the relative (virtual) address or the physical address in where the variable located in the memory?

And another question regarding memory management:

Why does this code produce the same stack pointer value for each run (from *Shellcoder's Handbook*, page 28)?
Does any program that I run produce this address?

```
// find_start.c
unsigned long find_start(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}
int main()
{
    printf("0x%x\n",find_start());
}
```

If we compile this and run this a few times, we get:

```
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ ./find_start
0xbffffad8
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ ./find_start
0xbffffad8
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ ./find_start
0xbffffad8
shellcoders@debian:~/chapter_2$ ./find_start
0xbffffad8
```

I would appreciate if someone could clarify this topic to me.

Comment: You don't get to see physical addresses under a typical OS. Only virtual. "Relative" is a totally different thing. Stack address is usually randomized, it might not be on your system. However that is broken inline assembly so it might not even be returning the stack pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, could you explain more in depth ?

Comment: afaik as far as the standard is concerned adresses of object could in principle be anything. Only for addresses to objects inside an array it makes certain guarantess

Comment: A better way to get a rough estimate of the stack pointer is to take the address of a local variable. If you want the inline asm version it should be something more like `void* esp; __asm__("movl %%esp, %0" : "=a"(esp)); return esp;`

Comment: Unless you are designing an OS driver, or a piece of the OS in general, you won't see physical addresses in normal circumstances. It's not a part of the OS<->process interface. This is vaguely similar to how the filesystem hides disk details (sectors/tracks/etc) to the user, exposing only file names in the interface.

Comment: I still don't get it. the virtual addresses are only per program ? lets say I have 2 programs; program1 and program2. can program2 access program1's memory ? 
In stack overflow example in the book I mentioned, they overwrite the return address in the stack to an address of an exploit in the enviroment variables. how does it work  ?

Comment: Your function has all kinds of undefined behaviour and will only work if you compile with optimization disabled.  (`asm` writing a register without telling the compiler about it with an output operand, and falling off the end of a non-`void` function.)  This will blow up in your face if your function inlines, or compiles to a `ud2` because of falling off the end with no return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I print a variable's address, is it showing the relative ( virtual ) address or the physical address in where the variable located in the memory ?

The counterpart to a relative address is an absolute address. That has nothing to do with the distinction between [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and physical addresses.

On most common modern operating systems, such as Windows, Linux and MacOS, unless you are writing a driver, you will never encounter physical addresses. These are handled internally by the operating system. You will only be working with virtual addresses.

> Why does this code produces the same stack pointer value for each run ( from shellcoder's handbook , page 28) ?

On most modern operating systems, every process has its own [virtual memory address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). The executable is loaded to its preferred base address in that virtual address space, if possible, otherwise it is loaded at another address (relocated). The preferred base address of an executable file is normally stored in its header. Depending on the operating system and CPU, the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP) is probably created at a higher address, since the heap normally grows upward (towards higher addresses). Because the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) normally grows downward (towards lower addresses), it will likely be created below the load address of the executable and grow towards the address 0.

Since the preferred load address is the same every time you run the executable, it is likely that the virtual memory addresses are the same. However, this may change if [address layout space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is used. Also, just because the virtual memory addresses are the same does not mean that the physical memory address are the same, too.

> Does any program that I will run produce this address ?

Depending on your operating system, you can set the preferred base address in which your program is loaded into virtual memory in the linker settings. Many programs may still have the same base address as your program, probably because both programs were built using the same linker with default settings.

> The virtual addresses are only per program? Let's say I have 2 programs: program1 and program2. Can program2 access program1's memory?

It is not possible for program2 to access program1's memory directly, because they have separate virtual memory address spaces. However, it is possible for one program to ask the operating system for permission to access another process's address space. The operating system will normally grant this permission, provided that the program has sufficient priviledges. On Windows, this is can be accomplished for example with the function [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory). Linux offers similar functionality by using [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) and writing to `/proc/[pid]/mem`. See [this link](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/09/03/) for further information.

Comment: In the example they provide in the book. They write a totally different program from the one they try to exploit with a shellcode, to determine the stack address. why would they do that ?

Comment: @DanielNagornov: One reason why a program may want to determine the stack address of another process would be to manipulate its [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), so that when the currently running function returns, it will jump to a different address, executing different code (which the attacking program injected). Another possible reason for wanting to determine the stack address would be if it wants to change the value of a function's local variable.

Comment: But how do they determine the stack address from a completely different program then, if two different program have different virtual memory address space ? how the example I showed above in the question helps determine the address that the exploit should overwrite in another program ?

Comment: @DanielNagornov: The stack pointer is not stored in the address space of the other process, but rather in one of the CPU registers. On Windows, you can suspend the target process with [SuspendThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-suspendthread) and then call [GetThreadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext) to read the CPU register contents of the target process. I'm not sure what the corresponding functions for Linux are.

Comment: @DanielNagornov: After doing some research, I found the corresponding function for Linux to be [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) with the parameter `PTRACE_PEEKUSER`. That parameter allows you to read the registers (including the stack pointer) of another process.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was looking for. The thing that confuses me is why did they do it the way they did it ( as I described, reading the stack pointer from another program to determine and guess the stack pointer address for the first program they intended to exploit ) they didn't use any of the functions mentioned here in the answers to ask from the os for the stack pointer of another process. they just used assembly to determine this address. I'm just wondering why this works, if it even does,  is it only just for this particular example they showed or is this a real method.

Comment: It doesn't work in general. Most of the simple exploit tutorials you can find don't work anymore. Obviously OS developers try to plug the holes as soon as they are found. So you have randomized addresses, non-executable stack/data/heap and other security features.

Comment: @DanielNagornov: I was able to find the book you mentioned on the internet. As stated in the book, this exploit will only works if [address layout space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (referred to in the book as the optional grsecurity patch) is not enabled. It seems that the exploit only targets Linux operating systems and it assumes that the stack address will always be the same if ASLR is not enabled. This information may still be correct, I don't know. I am not familiar with the internals of the Linux operating system.

Comment: @DanielNagornov: The 2nd edition of that book (which you probably have) is 13 years old. Meanwhile, it is much more common for Linux systems (and other operating systems too) to use [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), so that trick will likely no longer work. However, the book also describes ways to circumvent ASLR. I don't know if those tricks still work or not.

Answer (score 3):

You get virtual addresses. Your program never gets to see physical addresses. Ever.

> can program2 access program1's memory ?

**No**, because you can don't have addresses that point to program1's memory. If you have virtual address 0xabcd1234 in the program1 process, and you try to read it from the program2 process, you get program2's 0xabcd1234 (or a crash if there is no such address in program2). It's not a permission check - it's not like the CPU goes to the memory and sees "oh, this is program1's memory, I shouldn't access it". It's program2's own memory space.

But **yes**, if you use "shared memory" to ask the OS to put the same physical memory in both processes.

And **yes**, if you use `ptrace` or `/proc/<pid>/mem` to ask the OS nicely to read from the other process's memory, and you have permission to do that, then it will do that.

> why does this code produces the same stack pointer value for each run ( from shellcoder's handbook , page 28) ? does any program that I will run will produce this address ?

Apparently, *that* program always has that stack pointer value. Different programs might have different stack pointers. And if you put more local variables in `main`, or call `find_start` from a different function, you will get a different stack pointer value because there will be more data pushed on the stack.

Note: even if you run the program twice at the same time, the address will be the same, because they are virtual addresses, and every process has its own virtual address space. They will be different physical addresses but you don't see the physical addresses.

> In stack overflow example in the book I mentioned, they overwrite the return address in the stack to an address of an exploit in the enviroment variables. how does it work ?

It all works within one process.

Comment: so the enviroment variable is located in the process allocated memory ? this is why we can reach it's address ?

Comment: @DanielNagornov Yes. Otherwise the process wouldn't be able to read them. (I suppose it could ask the OS, but Linux is designed so it already has them and it doesn't need to ask the OS)

Comment: "Your program never gets to see physical addresses. Ever." - not _quite_ true. If you're writing user-space DMA then you might be passing the physical memory address of a UIO buffer to a hardware DMA controller. Granted, this is a pretty niche situation, and requires a specific driver (UIO) to expose the physical address via sysfs.

Answer (score -1):

Only focusing on a small part of your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// find_start.c
unsigned long find_start(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}
unsigned long nest ( void )
{
    return(find_start());
}
int main()
{
    printf("0x%lx\n",find_start());
    printf("0x%lx\n",nest());
}

gcc so.c -o so
./so
0x50e381a0
0x50e38190
```

There is no magic here.  The virtual space allows for programs to be built the same.  I don't need to know where my program is going to live, each program can be compiled for the same address space, when loaded and run the can see the same virtual address space because they are all mapped to separate/different physical address spaces.

```
readelf -a so
```

(don't but I prefer objdump)

objdump -D so

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000540 <_start>:
 540:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 542:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
 545:   5e                      pop    %rsi

....


000000000000064a <find_start>:
 64a:   55                      push   %rbp
 64b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 64e:   89 e0                   mov    %esp,%eax
 650:   90                      nop
 651:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 652:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000653 <nest>:
 653:   55                      push   %rbp
 654:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 657:   e8 ee ff ff ff          callq  64a <find_start>
 65c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 65d:   c3                      retq   

000000000000065e <main>:
 65e:   55                      push   %rbp
 65f:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 662:   e8 e3 ff ff ff          callq  64a <find_start>
 667:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
 66a:   48 8d 3d b3 00 00 00    lea    0xb3(%rip),%rdi        # 724 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 671:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 676:   e8 a5 fe ff ff          callq  520 <printf@plt>
 67b:   e8 d3 ff ff ff          callq  653 <nest>
```

So, two things or maybe more than two things.  Our entry point _start is in ram at a low address.  low virtual address. On this system with this compiler I would expect all/most programs to start in a similar place or the same or in some cases it may depend on what is in my program, but it should be somewhere low.

The stack pointer though, if you check above and now as I type stuff:

```
0x355d38d0
0x355d38c0
```

it has changed.

```
0x4ebf1760
0x4ebf1750

0x31423240
0x31423230

0xa63188d0
0xa63188c0
```

a few times within a few seconds.  The stack is a relative thing not absolute so there is no real need to create a fixed address that is the same every time. Needs to be in a space that is related to this user/thread and virtual since it is going through the mmu for protection reasons. There is no reason for a virtual address to not equal the physical address. The kernel code/driver that manages the mmu for a platform is programmed to do it a certain way. You can have the address space for code start at 0x0000 for every program, and you might wish the address space for data to be the same, zero based.  but for stack it doesn't matter. And on my machine, my os, this particular version this particular day it isn't consistent.

I originally thought your question was different depending on factors that are specific to your build, and settings. For a specific build a single call to find_start is going to be at a fixed relative address for the stack pointer each function that uses the stack will put it back the way it was found, assuming you can't change the compilation of the program while running the stack pointer for a single instance of the call the nesting will be the same the stack consumption by each function along the way will be the same.

I added another layer and by looking at the disassembly, main, nest and find_start all mess with the stack pointer (unoptimized) so that is why for these runs they are 0x10 apart.  if I added/removed more code per function to change the stack usage in one or more of the functions then that delta could change.

But

```
gcc -O2 so.c -o so
objdump -D so > so.txt
./so
0x0
0x0

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000560 <main>:
 560:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 564:   89 e0                   mov    %esp,%eax
 566:   48 8d 35 e7 01 00 00    lea    0x1e7(%rip),%rsi        # 754 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 56d:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
 56f:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 574:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 576:   e8 c5 ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
 57b:   89 e0                   mov    %esp,%eax
 57d:   48 8d 35 d0 01 00 00    lea    0x1d0(%rip),%rsi        # 754 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 584:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
 586:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 58b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 58d:   e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
 592:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 594:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 598:   c3                      retq
```

The optimizer didn't recognize the return value for some reason.

```
unsigned long fun ( void )
{
    return(0x12345678);
}

00000000000006b0 <fun>:
 6b0:   b8 78 56 34 12          mov    $0x12345678,%eax
 6b5:   c3                      retq
```

calling convention looks fine.

Put find_start in a separate file so the optimizer can't remove it

```
gcc -O2 so.c sp.c -o so
./so
0xb1192fc8
0xb1192fc8
./so
0x7aa979d8
0x7aa979d8
./so
0x485134c8
0x485134c8
./so
0xa8317c98
0xa8317c98
./so
0x2ba70b8
0x2ba70b8

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000560 <main>:
 560:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 564:   e8 67 01 00 00          callq  6d0 <find_start>
 569:   48 8d 35 f4 01 00 00    lea    0x1f4(%rip),%rsi        # 764 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 570:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 573:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 578:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 57a:   e8 c1 ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
 57f:   e8 4c 01 00 00          callq  6d0 <find_start>
 584:   48 8d 35 d9 01 00 00    lea    0x1d9(%rip),%rsi        # 764 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 58b:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 58e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 593:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 595:   e8 a6 ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
```

I didn't let it inline those functions it can see nest so it inlined it removing the stack change that came with it.  So now the value nested or not is the same.